# Non-unital rings: a few examples

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, rngs

Every ring I've ever heard of is unital, *i. e.*, contains a (unique) element $a$ such that $xa = ax = x$ for every $x$ in it. However, some rings do not have such an element. What are they?

*P. S.*: one will notice I assumed commutativity. So, for an easier related request, some examples of non-commutative rings would also be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-ring#Examples

Comment: How about even integers?

Comment: A very common example is the ring of functions with compact support over a noncompact space. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16168/applications-of-rings-without-identity/16171#16171

Comment: @Sivaram Oh, yes, $k\mathbb{Z}$ for $k > 1$ integer, of course. They should have occurred to me.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles I didn't know about the term pseudo-ring and the null rings. Nice.

Comment: Why are non-commutative examples easier? Are you paying by the property? :)

Comment: Good link Arturo, very pertinent. The guy gave a great answer.

Comment: Since you mention that the identity element is "probably" unique, here's a proof it *is* unique: Suppose a,b are identity elements. Then a=ab=b.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer Even shorter proof than I thought. I'd said "provably", BTW. Thanks, now I'm 100% sure of the uniqueness. I'll edit that part.

Comment: **See also** this related meta thread [Does anyone believe that there are rings without unit elements?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909/does-anyone-believe-that-there-are-rings-without-unit-elements#comment14615_3909)

Comment: See also in mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22579/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any ideal in a ring is itself a ring (but generally without unity, unless it's the full ring). So, there are plenty of examples.

Comment: This does indeed give lots of examples, but it doesn't *always* give an example. The ideal may have a unit different from the unit of the whole ring. For example, $R \times \{0 \}$ and $\{0 \} \times S$ are both ideals in the product ring $R \times S$.

Comment: Well, as soon as you have an idempotent, the principal ideal generated by this idempotent is a unital ring (the unit is the idempotent itself. (Ah, I see that Chris Eagle made the same point).

Comment: Right, so take the ring to be a domain and then there are no non-trivial idempotents. This still gives plenty of examples.

Comment: You don't need to require the ring to be a domain, just take a ring with a connected spectrum.

Answer (score 23):

One general source of such examples is functional analysis.

One of the easiest examples to describe is the space $C_{0}{(X)}$ of functions vanishing at infinity, where $X$ is locally compact, with pointwise addition and multiplication as operations. This ring is commutative and it is unital if and only if $X$ is compact.

Another class of examples is formed by the [convolution algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_algebra#The_convolution_algebra_L1.28G.29) $L^{1}(G)$ of a locally compact group $G$. It is unital if and only if $G$ is discrete and it is commutative if and only if $G$ is commutative. So probably the easiest examples of this kind would be $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ or $L^{1}(\mathbb{S^1})$. Related but a bit more complicated are the group $C^{\ast}$-algebras.

A completely different kind of (non-commutative) example would be the algebra of compact operators of an infinite-dimensional Banach space.

Comment: If $X$ is a non compact Hausdorff topological space, the ring of complex functions on $X$ has an interesting feature : if $K \subset X$ is a compact subset of $X$ then the ideal of functions supported on $K$ is an unital ring (the unity being $1_K$). This shows a non unital ring can have many unital subrings, none of which have the same unity.

Comment: @Joel: $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a compact subset of a noncompact Hausdorff space, but the ideal in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ of functions vanishing on $\mathbb{R}\setminus[0,1]$ is nonunital.  Do you mean when $K$ is open and compact?  Or did you really mean the ring of *all* complex functions on $X$?  (I suspect not, because this would be unital and would make the topological assumptions irrelevant.)

Comment: @Jonas : Ah yes, sorry, I meant $K$ **open** compact (I was thinking about a totally disconnected space $X$). It's a major omission indeed :)

Answer (score 18):

Non-unital rings are employed heavily in the general study of radical theories for rings. Perhaps you will find the following remarks of interest, excerpted from the preface of [Gardner and Wiegandt: *Radical Theory of Rings*, 2004](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824750330).

> Some authors deal exclusively with rings with unity element. This assumption is all right and not restrictive, *if the ring is ﬁxed*, as in module theory or group ring theory or sometimes investigating polynomial rings and power series rings (if the ring of coefficients does not possess a unity element. the indeterminate x is not a member of the polynomial ring). Dealing, however, simultaneously with several objects in a category of rings, demanding the existence of a unity element leads to a bizarre situation. Rings with unity element include among their fundamental operations the nullary operation $\mapsto$ 1 assigning the unity element. Thus in the category of rings with unity element the morphisms, in particular the monomorphisms, have to preserve also this nullary operation: subrings (i.e. subobjects) have to contain the same unity element, and so a proper ideal with unity element is not a subring, although a ring and a direct summand; there are no inﬁnite direct sums, no nil rings, no Jacobson radical rings, the ﬁnite valued linear transformations of an inﬁnite dimensional vector space do not form a ring, etc. Thus, in many, maybe most, branches of ring theory the requirement of the existence of a unity element is not sensible, and therefore unacceptable. This applies also to radical theory. and so *in this book rings need not have a unity element*.

For a somehwat different viewpoint see Bjorn Poonen's [Why all rings should have a 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0135).

Comment: image was OCR'ed surprisingly well by http://www.newocr.com/

Comment: **See also** this related meta thread [Does anyone believe that there are rings without unit elements?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909/does-anyone-believe-that-there-are-rings-without-unit-elements#comment14615_3909)

Comment: "Thus, in many, maybe most, branches of ring theory the requirement of the existence of a unity element is not sensible, and therefore unacceptable."

An example of the exceptions: The category of commutative rings with unity is fundamental in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 5):

A simple example would be the ring of ($ n \times n $)-matrices over $ 2 \mathbb{Z} $. This is a non-commutative ring without an identity.

Comment: I got confused for a second. This is really the ring of matrices with even entries, not the matrices of $\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

A ring is called generalized Boolean if $a^2 = a$ for every element $a$.
It can be easily proved that a generalized Boolean ring is commutative and $a + a = 0$ for every element $a$.
A generalized Boolean ring with a unity is called a Boolean ring.
As will be shown below, a Boolean ring can be identified with a Boolean algebra.
It is well known, by [Stone's representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras), that a Boolean algebra corresponds canonically to a compact totally disconnected space.
I will explain that a generalized Boolean ring corresponds canonically to a locally compact totally disconnected space.

Let $B$ be a lattice, i.e. a partially ordered set in which any two elements have a supremum and an infimum. $B$ is called a generalized Boolean algebra if it satisfies the following conditions.

(1) $B$ has a least element $0$.

(2) Let $a, b, c$ be elements of $B$.

$a\cap(b\cup c) = (a\cap b)\cup (a\cap c)$

$a\cup (b\cap c) = (a\cup b)\cap (a\cup c)$

(3) Let $a \in B$. there exists $b'$ such that $b\cap b' = 0, b\cup b' = a$ for every $b \le a$

A Boolean algebra is characterized as a generalized Boolean algebra with a greatest element(denoted by $1$).
The following is a typical example of a generalized Boolean algebra.

Let $X$ be a set.
Let $\Phi$ be a non-empty subset of the power set $P(X)$.
$\Phi$ is called a ring of sets on $X$ if it satisfies the following conditions.

Let $A, B$ be arbitrary elements of $\Phi$.

(1) $A\cup B \in \Phi$.

(2) $A \backslash B \in \Phi$.

Then $\Phi$ is a generalized Boolean algebra with the inclusion order.

Let $B, C$ be generalized Boolean algebra.
Let $f\colon B \rightarrow C$ be a map.
$f$ is called a homomorphism if it satisfies the following properties.

$f(a\cup b) = f(a) \cup f(b)$

$f(a\cap b) = f(a) \cap f(b)$

$f(0) = 0$

When $B$ and $C$ are Boolean algebras, $f$ is called a homomorphism of Boolean algebras if $f(1) = 1$.

Let $B$ be a generalized Boolean algebra.
Let $a, b \in B$.
There exists $c \in B$ such that $a \le c, b \le c$(for example $c = a \cup b$).
There exists $b' \in B$ such that $b\cap b' = 0, b\cup b' = c$.
It can be proved that $a\cap b'$ does not depend on a choice of $c$.
We denote $a \cap b'$ by $a \backslash b$.
We denote $(a\backslash b)\cup(b\backslash a)$ by $a\triangle b$ and call it the symmetric difference of $a$ and $b$.
It can be easily proved that $B$ is a generalized Boolean ring with addition $\triangle$ and multiplication $\cap$.

Conversely let $A$ be a generalized Boolean ring.
We denote $a \le b$ if $ab = a$.
It can be easily proved that this is an order relation and $A$ is a generalized Boolean algebra with this order.

Let $GBoolRng$ be the category of generalized Boolean rings(the morphisms are homomorphisms).
Let $GBoolAlg$ be the category of generalized Boolean algebras(the morphisms are homomorphisms).
Let $\mathcal{Set}$ be the category of small sets.
Let $U\colon GBoolRng \rightarrow \mathcal{Set}$, 
Let $V\colon GBoolAlg \rightarrow \mathcal{Set}$ be the canonical functors(i.e. the forgetful functors).

By the above results, we get a functor $F\colon GBoolRng \rightarrow GBoolAlg$ and a functor $G\colon GBoolAlg \rightarrow GBoolRng$.
It is easy to see that $U = VF, V = UG, GF = 1, FG = 1$.
Hence we can identify a generalized Boolean ring with a generalized Boolean algebra.
It can be easily seen that there exists a similar result concerning Boolean rings and Boolean algebras.

Let $A$ be a generalized Boolean algebra.
Let $F_2$ be the two element Boolean algebra.
A homomorphism $\chi\colon A \rightarrow F_2$ is called a character of $A$ if $\chi \neq 0$.
We denote by $X(A)$ the set of characters of $A$.
Let $F_2^{A}$ be the set of maps $A \rightarrow F_2$.
We consider $F_2^{A}$ as a topological space with the product topology, where $F_2$ is endowed with discrete topology.
We consider $X(A)$ as a topological space with the subspace topology induced by $F_2^{B}$.
It can be proved that $X(A)$ is a locally compact totally disconnected Hausdorff space.
Let $S(X(A))$ be the set of compact open subsets of $X(A)$.
It is easy to see that $S(X(A))$ is a generalized Boolean algebra with the inclusion order.
Then the following theorem holds.

**Generalized Stone's representation theorem**
Let $A$ be a generalized Boolean algebra.
For $a \in A$, we denote by $a^*$ the set $\{\chi\in X(A)\colon \chi(a) = 1\}$.
Then $a^* \in S(X(A))$.
We define a map $\rho\colon A \rightarrow S(X(A))$ by $\rho(a) = a^*$.
Then $\rho$ is an isomorphism of generalized Boolean algebras.

Comment: Just some small remarks: What you call "generalized Stone representation theorem" was proved by Stone himself in §2 on pp. 383ff of [Applications of the theory of Boolean rings to general topology](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1937-1501905-7) and it is the original topological form of Stone's duality theorems, see also the earlier article [The theory of representations for Boolean algebras](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1936-1501865-8). Also, it seems more widespread to call a ring Boolean if $a^2 = a$ for all $a$ and call it a Boolean algebra if it has a unit (no generalized).

Comment: @commenter Thanks for the links. I didn't know Stone proved "Generalized Stone representation theorem".
Though I proved it by myself, I guessed it was well known among specialists in Boolean algebras.Actually it is not difficult to prove it if you know the proof of Stone representation theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example which comes up occasionally for me: Let $C$ be a category and $k$ a field. Define the "category algebra" $kC$ to be the free vector space on $\bigsqcup_{X,Y \ \in \mathrm{Ob}(C)} \mathrm{Hom}_C(X,Y)$, with multiplication $\alpha \beta = \alpha \circ \beta$ if the target of $\beta$ is the source of $\alpha$, and $0$ otherwise. (So this generalizes the group algebra of a group and the path algebra of a quiver.) If $\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ is finite, then $\sum_{X \in \mathrm{Ob}(C)} \mathrm{Id}_X$ is the identity but, if there are infinitely many objects, there is no identity.

Answer (score 0):

1. For an open subset of a topological space $A\subset X$, the relative (singular) cohomology rng $H^\ast(X,A)$ with relative cup-product as multiplication generally does not posses a unit. For instance, let $X$ be the $2$-torus and $A$ the circle embedded into $A$ as a meridian. Then $H^0(X,A)\cong \tilde{H^0} (X/A)\cong 0$, since $(X,A)$ is a good pair. As $H^\ast(X,A)$ is a $\mathbb{N}$-graded non-zero rng, it thus is non-unital.
2. For a silly example, consider any abelian group $G$ with at least two elements and set $a\cdot b :=0_G$ for all $a,b\in G.$
3. An infinite direct sum of non-zero (unital) rings is non-unital.