# $ \mathbb Z$ is not isomorphic to any proper subring of itself.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that  the ring $ \mathbb Z$  is not isomorphic to any proper subring of itself.

Is the cardinality main reason for not being isomorphic??

Please Help!!

Comment: Are you asking for subrings to share the unit of the original ring? In such case $\Bbb Z$ may only have $0$ has the only subring, which other people might not even call a ring.

Comment: It's not cardinality. Think about the subrings $n\mathbb{Z}$. They are all infinite too. Can you build an isomorphism to any of them?

Comment: I belong to the church believing that all rings have a multiplicative neutral element. Your teacher apparently doesn't. But, humoring them, which subrings of $\Bbb{Z}$ have a neutral element? Isn't having a neutral element a property preserved by isomorphisms? According to anyone's definition!

Comment: I think it might be helpful to state the definition of "ring" used in your class / book.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: In commutative algebra, it's part of the definition. But a lot of book (e.g. Dummit & Foote) doesn't assume this condition when introducing ring, subring...

Comment: Sigh. @Krish: The topic has been discussed THOROUGHLY on our site. For example [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12937/11619). Hmm, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48587/11619) is a better fit. I did say **believing** :-). Dummit & Foote do not have authority over all practitioners.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Maybe the teacher wanted to see if his students understood well what a ring isomorphism is, in particular, if they notice that the unit is sent to an unit.

Comment: @user26857 More than "understanding", it is a matter of *definition*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're being evil and heretical against the D&F Church of the Last Equations! Repent or burn forever in a nilpotent matrix.

Comment: @Timbuc [Some people](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RingHomomorphism.html) don't consider $f(1)=1$ as part of the definition.

Comment: @user26857 Mopre = more in typonese. And you're making *precisely* my point: the issue here, beyond or even *before* understanding, is **knowing** (and understanding, of course) what the definition given by the teacher/book is.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Watch at Jyrki!  Dummit and Foote are known to hand out [abstract $\forall \! \iint$ kickings!](http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~rfoote/Dummit-Foote.JPG)

Answer (score 7):

Let $f:\mathbb Z\to A$ be a ring isomorphism, where $A\subsetneq\mathbb Z$ is a subring. Then $f(1)=a\in A$, and from $f(1)^2=f(1)$ we get $a=1$ or $a=0$. In the first case $A=\mathbb Z$, a contradiction, while in the second $f$ isn't injective (recall that $f(0)=0$).

For short, $\mathbb Z$ has no proper *unitary* subrings.