# Are the authors sloppy when forgetting the property "with unity" of $\mathbb Z$ in Remark (b)?

Tags: ring-theory, proof-explanation, rational-numbers

I am reading Section 9. *The Rational Numbers* from textbook *Analysis I* by *Amann/Escher*. They present two theorems:

> [image]
>   [image]

and then say

> [image]

It is stated in Theorem 9.1 that $\mathbb Z$ is a smallest *domain* **with unity**, but it is stated in Remark (b) that "all that was necessary was that $\mathbb Z$ be a *domain*" and that "*any domain* $R$ is a subring of
a unique (up to isomorphism) minimal field $Q$".

**My question:** Are the authors sloppy when forgetting the property **with unity** of $\mathbb Z$ and $R$ in Remark (b)?

Comment: It is currently a common though not universal practice to treat *ring* as having a multiplicative identity: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48587/definition-of-ring-vs-rng/48612 (some people call the structure without a  multiplicative identity a *rng*) and so also a *domain*.  Perhaps they mentioned this in 9.1 to be helpful but did not in 9.2 as they felt they had already done so.

Comment: @Henry ... and as the question shows, this attempt to being helpful can turn out to be confusing instead. -- For clarity, we woul dneed to see the sections of the book where the corresponding definitions are made

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen which corresponding definitions do you like to see in my textbook? I will update my post then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplicative identity is not necessary for [the construction of field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions#Construction). If $R$ is integral domain, and $Q$ its field of fractions, $R$ embeds into $Q$ by $r\mapsto \frac{rs}s$, for any $s\in R\setminus\{0\}$ (and doesn't depend on choice of $s$).

Comment: We should note that "integral domain" commonly means **non-trivial** commutative ring without zero-divisors, and the non-triviality condition was (sloppily) left out in Theorem 9.1