# Does every ID with subring which has a unity have an unity?

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

For an arbitrary ID (integral domain) $R$ with subring $S$, assume that $S$ has an unity. Then does $R$ have a unity too? If not, please provide a counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is nontrivial (that is, has a nonzero identity $e$) then yes.

A nonzero idempotent in a domain must act as the identity for the domain.

To see this, just examine what $e(ex-x)$ and $(xe-x)e$ must be, where $x$ is an arbitrary element of the domain.

This came up under slightly different circumstances [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/663635/29335).

Comment: If $e$ is the identity, then won't $ex=x$ and therefore $ex-x=0$?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt:  As a general rule, it's unproductive to assume that which you are attempting to prove.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see the significance of $e(ex-x)$. Ok, if you multiply $e$ by $e(ex-x)$, then you get $e(ex-x)$ because $e$ is idempotent. So if any element can be written as $ex-x$, then $e$ is an identity. However, how can that be possible when $ex-x$ is always $0$?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt:  What's being claimed here is not that any element can be written as $ex-x$, but that every element can be written as $x$.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt The *conclusion* is that $ex-x=xe-x=0$, and therefore $e$ is the identity. It is not the hypothesis...

Comment: Ah ok got it - using the distributive property, $e(ex-x)=e^2x-ex=ex-ex=0$. As it's an integral domain and $e\neq 0$, we must have $ex-x=0$ and hence $ex=x$, so $e$ is the identity. Thanks