# If $R$ in an integral domain, and $C$ is a field containing $R$ then, Is the unit of R and the unit of C the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to answer the following question,

If $ R $ in an integral domain, and $ C $ is a field containing $ R $ then, Is the unit of R and the unit of C the same?

I'm beginning to suspect that the answer is that they do not necessarily have to be the same, but I do not find a counterexample either.
I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: When you say "unit", do you mean "multiplicative identity element"?

Comment: Do you know that the multiplicative identity elements in any integral domain or field is unique? (If $1$ and $1'$ are two multiplicative identity elements, then $1 = 1 1' = 1'$.)

Comment: Hint: what happens when you multiply the multiplicative identity of $R$ by the multiplicative identity of $C$?

Comment: @AlexMacedo It will give the identity of the ring, but not necessarily the identity of the field as long as you don't know that they are the same.

Comment: @Bemte  I am assuming the OP meant that multiplication and addition on $C$ restrict to the multiplication and addition on $R$. Since we're in a field, wouldn't $$1_{R}(1_R - 1_{R'}) = 0$$ give the desired result?

Comment: @AlexMacedo That is clever and you are right, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for the simple reason that domains (with identity) only have two idempotents: $\{0,1\}$.

There are only two idempotents in $C$, and there are only two idempotents in $R$... so obviously $0_R=0_C$ and $1_R=1_C$.

In fact, a more general formulation makes the statement even more obvious:

> Proposition: Let $R\subseteq C$ be two nontrivial rings with identities (not assumed to be equal. If both $C$ has only trivial idempotents, then $1_C=1_R$.

As a corollary you get the theorem when $C$ is a domain, or a local ring, or any other type of ring that lacks nontrivial idempotents.

Comment: In fact [one can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/663635/29335) that any rng which has no nonzero zero divisors, a nonzero idempotent must be an identity for the rng.

Comment: May I ask what someone found objectionable about this?

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a subring of $C$, then yes, their units coincide. That is due to the fact that "containing" needs to be well defined. Take for example the ring
$$R = \{a,b\}$$
such that $a+a = b + b = 0, a+b = b+a = b, ab = aa = a, bb = b$.

This is the binary field, if we put $a = 0$ and $b = 1$.

However, this might be contained (as a set), in $\{a,b,c\}$, which we can give the relations of the finite field with three elements such that in this case, $a$ gets the role of $1$, $b$ the role of zero.

It is because of such problems, that we have to define "contained" properly. This is done by saying:

> A Ring $R$ can be considered a subring of a ring $S$, if there is an injective ring homomorphism $\phi : R \to S$.
>   (see below for an example)

Often, $R$ gets identified with its image $\phi(R)$ and then it looks like as if $R$ is really a subset of $S$, but you always have to keep in mind this definition.
This way to see it also helps with your problem, as a ring homomorphism always has to map the one of $R$ to the one of $S$, and thus with regard to your question, yes, they are the same.

> Example: Consider the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and the rational field, $\mathbb{Q}$. Every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ is of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \neq 0$. We can embed $\mathbb{Z}$ into this field through
>   $$\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}, a \mapsto \frac{a}{1}$$
>   and thus often simply say that $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, dropping the denominator $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's true, but the hypotesis of $C$ being a field it's definetely fundamental. Indeed let $R$ be the ring of the matrices of the following form

$$ \left(\matrix{ 
a & 0   \cr
0 & 0   \cr }\right)$$
It's a ring and identity is obtained with $a=1$. This is clearly different from the identity of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ which is
$$ \left(\matrix{ 
1 & 0   \cr
0 & 1   \cr }\right)$$
And invertible elements in $R$ are not invertible in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.Of course the latter is not a field so it doesn't implicate anything on your exercise but the need of the hypotesis of $C$ being a field.

Now let us suppose $C$ is a field and $R$ an integral domain in $C$ if $R$ contains the unit of $C$ then is evident since
$$1_R 1_C=1_C=1_C 1_C$$ thenit follows from the cancellation law since it's an integral domain that
$$1_R=1_C$$
from that assertion the invertible elements are the same.

So I think you should restate you question in if $C$ is a field and $R$ an integral domain does $R$ has to contain the identity of $C$? If yes then the exercise it follows if not you have the counterexample.

Comment: $C$ being a field isn't really *fundamental* here... it's *sufficient*... but so is the assumption that $C$ is merely a domain, or is a local ring, or...

Comment: Yes, I didn't read your answer. Now I guess mine is superfluos